# how to reach object property with variable in php

Tags: php

I have

```
foreach(["ge","en","ru"] as $lang)
        {
            Tour_trans::create([
                "tour_id" => $tour->id,
                "lang_id" => Langs::where('lang', $lang)->first()->id,
                "title" => $data["" . $lang . "_title"],
                "location" => $data["" . $lang . "_location"],
                "dept_time" => $data["" . $lang . "_dept_time"],
                "depture_time" => $data["" . $lang . "_dept_time"],
                "return_time" => $data["" . $lang . "_return_time"],
                "body" => $data["" . $lang . "_body"],
                "days" => $data["all_days"]->$lang
            ]);
        }
```

$data is a json object. everything works fine except last line

```
"days" => $data["all_days"]->$lang
```

i got error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.
in $data["all_days] there are 3 array objects - ge, en, ru. so i want to reach this property in loop

Comment: show us a `var_dump` of `$data` var

Comment: What is your json result?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the choice of the second parameter of `json_decode`:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

If `$assoc` is set to true, then you get back an associative array. If it is set to false, then you get an object.